# Log Parser SQL query formatting to search for specific keyword within certain timeframe?

Tags: sql, iis, scripting, smtp, logparser

I am using Microsoft LogParser Studio v2.2 GUI to parse the IIS SMTP relay servers, I wonder what's the SQL query to get the string with the specified email address Super.User@domain.org and between certain time frame like from 1/6/2020 until today?

The line example from IISLOG is:

```
144.42.115.31, OutboundConnectionCommand, 4/06/2020, 2:25:52, SMTPSVC1, PRDMAIL05-VM, -, 187, 0, 4, 0, 0, MAIL, -, FROM:<Super.User@domain.org> SIZE=3159,
82.55.126.143, OutboundConnectionCommand, 8/06/2020, 12:54:52, SMTPSVC1, PRDMAIL05-VM, -, 187, 0, 4, 0, 0, MAIL, -, TO:<Super.User@domain.org> SIZE=4822,
```

I have tried the below code, but it does not show anything on the result:

```
SELECT logfilename, 
       logrow, 
       userip, 
       username, 
       To_localtime(To_timestamp(date, time)) AS timestamp, 
       hostname, 
       requesttype, 
       parameters 
FROM   '[LOGFILEPATH]' 
WHERE  ( parameters LIKE '%Super.User@domain.org%' 
       AND    timestamp >= '1/06/2020 12:00 AM' 
       AND    timestamp <= '9/06/2020 12:00 PM' )
```

Throws the error:

> --------------------------- Log Parser Studio
> --------------------------- Error parsing query: WHERE clause: Semantic Error: content field "1/06/2020 12:00 AM" doesn't match type
> of left-operand "timestamp" [SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.]
>
> New Query
>
> IISLOG
> --------------------------- OK
>
> ---

After using TO_LOCALTIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time)) AS timestamp the column timestamp in LogParser GUI is showing

```
4/06/2020 12:25:52 PM
4/06/2020 5:06:38 PM
```

While the actual log file is showing respectively:

```
4/06/2020, 2:25:52
4/06/2020, 7:06:38
```

The log file directories are 50 GB+ and it is using IISLOG as the type.

Comment: In your WHERE clause you want to make sure that LogParser understands the timestamp constant that you're passing as an actual timestamp: `AND timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2020-06-01 12:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`. Also make sure you nail down the timezones, and don't mix up local time with UTC time.

Comment: Cool, thanks @GabrieleGiuseppini. So how do I convert it into my Timezone?

Comment: You may use `TO_LOCALTIME`. Have a look at https://documentation.help/Log-Parser/DT_Timestamp.htm, there's quite a few tips there.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion :-) I appreciate it very much.